# Android BaseAdapter cannot load the last Array Value

Tags: android

everybody

Recently I have use ADT to develop the android 2.2 program. The program run correctly in the simulator, but it meet a strange problem when it run in the real machine.

I use BaseAdapter to create a MenuAdapter, it will load the custom class called ViewHolder. Both the custom class and MenuAdapter is similar to any sample about BaseAdapter: ViewHolder only have two variable text and image, without any codes. MenuAdapter load the Menu layout that contain a TextView. It will assign the text variable in the TextView and load it as Alert Dialog repeatly.

Then I create array carry the following variable:

```
public String[] menuOptions={"Browser", "Google Map", "Camera", "Gallery", "Media Player", "Cancel", "Exit"};
```

After then, I use the AlertDialog.Builder().setAdapter() to create the BaseAdapter object and load the array in. The Alert Dialog carry on the data set. But it output this:

> Browser, Google Map, Camera, Gallery, Media Player, Cancel, Browser

The last item change in random, I load the Alert Dialog again and it can turn out this:

> Browser, Google Map, Camera, Gallery, Media Player, Cancel, Google Map
>
> Browser, Google Map, Camera, Gallery, Media Player, Cancel, Gallery

no Exit...

So I want to know, what is going on? Why it does not load all the data? When I meet this problem, I try to reduce the Array to

```
public String[] menuOptions={"Browser", "Google Map", "Camera", "Gallery", "Media Player", "Cancel"};
```

It display correctly:

> Browser, Google Map, Camera, Gallery, Media Player, Cancel

There is no numeric setting about the array loading in the MenuAdapter Class, so I don't understand about this.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to load the ListAdapter and pass it to the dialog builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer.

The Dialog Alert display in wrong data because some of the data is displayed outside the screen. Dialog alert  will display them in scroll-y style (if you know what HTML and CSS is then you will know what I mean).

The data that hides in the scroll-y style will display in random......for example, my last item  "Exit" is hide under the screen when I load in, I drag down the screen to review, it will display the last data in random, not "Exit".

I solve it in changing the line height of each items, make them shorter, make them display in one screen without scroll-y style and it will display the data correctly.

I don't know if it is system bug or not.